How Tex ignore the special characters and can automatically wrap the new line for a too long text?
I have some content that originates from different websites, and it may contain special characters such as %, _, &, /, etc. I want to display this content correctly while ensuring that the special characters are ignored and the content is presented properly. The \verb| | command can achieve this, but it doesn't automatically handle line breaks for long text, which can result in part of the content not being displayed. Is there any way to achieve this behavior with proper line wrapping?
In LaTex, the \verb| | can ignore the all special characters but cannot wrap automatically.
Test file test.tex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle

\section{Section1}
\textbf{URL}: \verb| https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx%20&%20xxxxxxxxxxxx%2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%20(2024)_Just%20Accepted-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pdf| \\

\end{document}

In this example, the URL is too long to be displayed properly in the PDF.
When the content inside \url{} is too long and automatically wraps to the next line and next page, the page number also becomes part of the hyperlink. This causes the page number to be clickable, which is not the desired behavior.(e.g. The page number "7" also becomes part of the URL hyperlink. )


To solve the problem with page number inside urls. According to the answer How do I forbid pagebreaks inside urls without forbidding linebreaks?, what I did was to add the following two lines of code at the very beginning of Tex and it solved the problem.
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{}


If all of the problematic strings are urls, you could use \url{...} (possibly combined with the xurl package to allow more possible break points)

more generally, you could e.g. use minted, which has an option to allow line breaks in inline code:



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\url{https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx%20&%20xxxxxxxxxxxx%2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%20(2024)_Just%20Accepted-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pdf}

\mintinline[breaklines,breakanywhere]{text}|https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx%20&%20xxxxxxxxxxxx%2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%20(2024)_Just%20Accepted-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pdf| 

\end{document}



When the content inside \url{} is too long and automatically wraps to the next line and next page, the page number also becomes part of the hyperlink. This causes the page number to be clickable, which is not the desired behavior. (I've just updated the question with a new example to better illustrate the problem.)

@AlbertYang https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578405/36296

Thank you so much for your help, this solution was really useful and solved my issue.
